# can't build lambdabot with ghc-7.8 (@ haskell-src-exts)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was trying to install `lambdabot` with ghc-7.8.2, but encountered an error while installing `haskell-src-exts`. To diagnose the issue, I tried

```
cabal install haskell-src-exts -v3
```

and get the following errors. I am using Windows XP 64-bit. I don't know if this has anything to do with spaces in windows directory names. Any ideas/pointer how to fix the problem?

```
...
[_18] next goal: array (dependency of haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1)
[_18] trying: array-0.5.0.0/installed-d6d...
[_19] done
Ready to install haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1
Extracting C:\Documents and Settings\ting\Application
Waiting for install task to finish...
Data\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org\haskell-src-exts\1.15.0.1\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1.tar.gz
to C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008...
Renaming
'C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist'
to
'C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist-tmp'.
creating
C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist
Renaming
'C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist-tmp'
to
'C:\DOCUME~1\ting\LOCALS~1\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-3008\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist'.
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Documents and Settings\ting\Application Data\cabal\logs\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1.log ):
cabal.exe: C:\Documents and Settings\ting\Application
Data\cabal\logs\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1.log: does not exist
```

Comment: Try to locate the log file. Add its content to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. I tried to locate the log file as the comments suggested. However, in the cabal/log folder, there are only two log files for hashtable and haskline after `running cabal-install lambdabot` on a fresh ghc-7.8 installation.

To see if this error has anything to do with the spaces in the default cabal directory, I used a folder without spaces and did manual installation:

```
$ cd /d/temp
$ cabal get haskell-src-exts
Unpacking to haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\
$ cd haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1/ && cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( dist\setup\setup.hs, dist\setup\Main.o )
Linking .\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1...
setup.exe: The program 'happy' version >=1.17 is required but it could not be
found.
```

So, `happy` in the dependency is somehow missing and undetected by cabal. It turns out `happy` too has an issue using the default `cabal install` command, and it can be overcome by a manual installation in, e.g., `/d/temp`,

```
cabal get happy && cd happy* && cabal configure && cabal install
```

This installs `happy` and doing the same for `haskell-src-exts` installs the package correctly. But there are other errors along the way for installing lambdabot, none of which seems to like the one encountered here with haskell-src-exts and happy.